# How to do performance testing of dynamic website?

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I want to check a weather data is rendered in a page or not dynamically when page is loaded in html.Also wanted to know weather data that has appended dynamically is valid or not.Wanted to know how can i check its performance and also any tool that  help in performing this task.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to imply that you need to check whether the page is correct during the performance test.  There is a price to be paid for checking correctness during a performance test:

- these tools are optimized for performance testing rather than functional testing, and so you may have to go through more effort to check a page's correctness than you would in a functional test using something like JUnit
- checking correctness will require your test machine(s) to work harder, so you may need to run the test on more machines in order to generate enough load

Here are some other options to consider:

- Make the performance test and the functional test separate tests.  Use a load-testing tool for the performance test, and something like JUnit for the functional test.
- Check the functional part by hand while the performance test is running.  This is what I normally do.

Answer (score 0):

In fact any load testing tool has validations and assertions. If you're looking for free and open source solution the most promising tools as for now are:

- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/#/)
- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

You can check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use), it highlights main features of aforementioned load testing tools, contains sample demo script and results and ends with comparison matrix.